# Enum size is the same after adding values to it

Tags: c#, enums

I had an original `enum` which size was 134 and the unit tests were failing. After adding more entries to it, the size remained the same.

`Enum.GetValues(typeof(AdaptedType)).Length;` still returns 134, although there are much more.

Why does it behave so weird?

The enum is below:

```
public enum AdaptedType
   {
#pragma warning disable 1591
      Undefined = -2,
      Custom = -1,
      Length = 0,
      Area = 1,
      Volume = 2,
      Angle = 3,
      Number = 4,
      SheetLength = 5,
      SiteAngle = 6,
      Density = 7,
      Energy = 8,
      Friction = 9,
      Power = 10,
      Power_Density = 11,
      Pressure = 12,
      Temperature = 13,
      Velocity = 14,
      Airflow = 15,
      DuctSize = 16,
      CrossSection = 17,
      HeatGain = 18,
      Electrical_Current = 19,
      Electrical_Potential = 20,
      Electrical_Frequency = 21,
      Electrical_Illuminance = 22,
      Electrical_Luminous_Flux = 23,
      Electrical_Power = 24,
      Roughness = 25,
      Force = 26,
      LinearForce = 27,
      AreaForce = 28,
      Moment = 29,
      ForceScale = 30,
      LinearForceScale = 31,
      AreaForceScale = 32,
      MomentScale = 33,
      Electrical_Apparent_Power = 34,
      Electrical_Power_Density = 35,
      Piping_Density = 36,
      Piping_Flow = 37,
      Piping_Friction = 38,
      Piping_Pressure = 39,
      Piping_Temperature = 40,
      Piping_Velocity = 41,
      Piping_Viscosity = 42,
      PipeSize = 43,
      Piping_Roughness = 44,
      Stress = 45,
      UnitWeight = 46,
      ThermalExpansion = 47,
      LinearMoment = 48,
      LinearMomentScale = 49,
      ForcePerLength = 50,
      ForceLengthPerAngle = 51,
      LinearForcePerLength = 52,
      LinearForceLengthPerAngle = 53,
      AreaForcePerLength = 54,
      Piping_Volume = 55,
      Viscosity = 56,
      CoefficientOfHeatTransfer = 57,
      Airflow_Density = 58,
      Slope = 59,
      Cooling_Load = 60,
      Cooling_Load_Divided_By_Area = 61,
      Cooling_Load_Divided_By_Volume = 62,
      Heating_Load = 63,
      Heating_Load_Divided_By_Area = 64,
      Heating_Load_Divided_By_Volume = 65,
      Airflow_Divided_By_Volume = 66,
      Airflow_Divided_By_Cooling_Load = 67,
      Area_Divided_By_Cooling_Load = 68,
      WireSize = 69,
      Piping_Slope = 71,
      Currency = 72,
      Electrical_Efficacy = 73,
      Electrical_Wattage = 74,
      Color_Temperature = 75,
      DecSheetLength = 76,
      Electrical_Luminous_Intensity = 77,
      Electrical_Luminance = 78,
      Area_Divided_By_Heating_Load = 79,
      Factor = 80,
      Electrical_Temperature = 81,
      Electrical_CableTraySize = 82,
      Electrical_ConduitSize = 83,
      Reinforcement_Volume = 84,
      Reinforcement_Length = 85,
      Electrical_Demand_Factor = 86,
      DuctInsulationThickness = 87,
      DuctLiningThickness = 88,
      PipeInsulationThickness = 89,
      ThermalResistance = 90,
      ThermalMass = 91,
      Acceleration = 92,
      Bar_Diameter = 93,
      Crack_Width = 94,
      Displacement_Deflection = 95,
      Structural_Frequency = 97,
      Mass = 98,
      Mass_per_Unit_Length = 99,
      Moment_of_Inertia = 100,
      Surface_Area = 101,
      Period = 102,
      Pulsation = 103,
      Reinforcement_Area = 104,
      Reinforcement_Area_per_Unit_Length = 105,
      Reinforcement_Cover = 106,
      Reinforcement_Spacing = 107,
      Rotation = 108,
      Section_Area = 109,
      Section_Dimension = 110,
      Section_Modulus = 111,
      Section_Property = 112,
      Structural_Velocity = 113,
      Warping_Constant = 114,
      Weight = 115,
      Weight_per_Unit_Length = 116,
      ThermalConductivity = 117,
      SpecificHeat = 118,
      SpecificHeatOfVaporization = 119,
      Permeability = 120,
      Electrical_Resistivity = 121,
      MassDensity = 122,
      MassPerUnitArea = 123,
      Pipe_Dimension = 124,
      PipeMass = 125,
      PipeMassPerUnitLength = 126,
      TemperatureDifference = 127,
      Piping_TemperatureDifference = 128,
      Electrical_TemperatureDifference = 129,
      TimeInterval = 130,
      Speed = 131,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020")]
      Stationing = 132,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      AngularSpeed = 133,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      CostPerArea = 134,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      CostRateEnergy = 135,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      CostRatePower = 136,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Diffusivity = 137,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Distance = 138,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      FlowPerPower = 139,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      HeatCapacityPerArea = 140,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      HvacMassPerTime = 141,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Image = 142,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Integer = 143,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      IsothermalMoistureCapacity = 144,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      LoadClassification = 145,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Material = 146,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      MultilineText = 147,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      NumberOfPoles = 148,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      PipingMassPerTime = 149,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      PowerPerFlow = 150,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      PowerPerLength = 151,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      RotationAngle = 152,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      StationingInterval = 153,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Text = 154,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      ThermalGradientCoefficientForMoistureCapacity = 155,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      Url = 156,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      WireDiameter = 157,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021")]
      YesNo = 158,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021, 2022")]
      ApparentPowerDensity = 159,
      [Obsolete("Use with care, not available in 2020, 2021, 2022")]
      FillPattern = 160,
#pragma warning restore 1591
   }
```

Comment: How is your code included in your unit tests, and how is it tested ? for example : could it be that your `AdaptedType` is masked by another type with same name coming from another unit ?

Comment: @LeGEC no, that's not the case. Those tests are very simple tests in which I am matching the sizes of the enum that I have and some other enum from a NuGet.

Comment: To ensure your enum is up to date, please try to refer new added enumeration like `Debug.Assert((int)AdaptedType.FillPattern == 160)` in the unit tests.

Comment: The original project might not be built. Do you add it as a project reference? And you can also check the configuration manager.

Comment: I've deleted the whole output folder, rebuilt the solution and the result is still the same.

Comment: Delete the reference in the unit tests project, then re-add it by selecting the Project tab. Oh... don't build the solution, build the projects one by one.

Comment: So I re-added the references, built the projects one by one, but the result is still the same. However, the assert it true.

Comment: Perhaps it also exists in another namespace?